# Get element index using class and subclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to get the index of a TR element which has two class the first one identify it like a group and the second one as a sub-group, then I try to get the index of a specific group and subgroup it returns me -1... Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Here is an example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="trusure1 trrstatusC"></tr>
    <tr class="trusure2 trrstatusC"></tr>
    <tr class="trusure2 trrstatusC"></tr>
    <tr class="trusure2 trrstatusR"></tr>
    <tr class="trusure2 trrstatusR"></tr>
    <tr class="trusure3 trrstatusC"></tr>
    <tr class="trusure3 trrstatusC"></tr>
</table>
<div id="console"></div>
    <script>
    $('#console').append('<br> The tr with the class trusure2 and the lastest with class trrstatusR is on the position '+$('tr.trusure2.trrstatusR:last-child').index());
<script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nod9xbsh/

Thank you!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: jsfiddle seems down, could you use codepen.io?

Comment: ^! This is a **PRIME** example of why the rule on SO is to post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that! Ive just edited my post to add a simple source example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$('tr.trusure2.trrstatusR:last').index()` instead

Comment: Oh didnt know about that selector, but makes sense since its not a child of another element.. Thank you Janar!